# .load gets the page, but doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using .load() to get the page from our server. The weird thing is, I can see using a debugger tool that the request was successful. I can see that it is part of the html using the element. I could also see that in the page source. BUT, it is not displaying.

When I try to hover the mouse pointer over the div code, It shows the part where the div is but the size is something like this 1683px X 0px

I've already tried reading other posts from stack that have the same problem as mine, but the answers didn't fix my problem.

I could not paste the entire code but I'll make sure I've posted everything that is needed.

```
function updateDefaultExchangeRate(){
    alert("grgd");
    var url = window.location.href
    url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf("index"));
    url = url += "updateDefaultExchangeRate";
    var params = "?sideMenuItem=10&";
    $('#defaultExchangeRateTable tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td #detail-currency').val()!=undefined) {
            params += "detail-currency=" + encodeURI($(this).find('td #detail-currency').val()) + "&";
            params += "detail-exchangeRateVal=" + encodeURI($(this).find('td #detail-exchangeRateVal').val()) + "&";
            params += "detail-id=" + encodeURI($(this).find('td #detail-id').val()) + "&";
            params += "detail-version=" + encodeURI($(this).find('td #detail-version').val()) + "&";
        }
    })

    url += params.substr(0,params.length-1)
    $('#defaultExchangeRateTable').load(url );

}
```

html page to be loaded

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>

<%
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
%>

<div id="exchangeRateTable">
    <div class="list-table">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                %{--<th style="width: 25px"/>--}%
                <th>Exchange Rate Date</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Exchange Rate</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <%  def currency = null
                if(exchangeRateInstanceList.size != 0) {
                currency = ListUtil.findCurrencyById(currencyInstanceList, exchangeRateInstanceList?.get(0).targetCurrencyId.toString())
            }
            %>

            <g:each in="${exchangeRateInstanceList}" status="i" var="exchangeRateInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                    <td>${exchangeRateInstance?.exchangeDate ? formatter.format(exchangeRateInstance?.exchangeDate) : ''}</td>
                    <td>${currency?.shortName}</td>
                    <td>${exchangeRateInstance?.exchangeRate ? String.format("%,.2f",exchangeRateInstance.exchangeRate) : '' }</td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

index, the page it has to be loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list-exchangeRate" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">

        <div id="mainRecordsList">

            <g:render template="indexDefaultExchangeRate" />
        </div>
        <g:render template="/layouts/pagination" model="${[instanceCount: exchangeRateInstanceCount]}"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, Im using grails.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a CSS problem -- if the element is in the DOM but showing with 0 width, check the CSS styles on that element to see if anything is effecting its size or display properties.

Comment: @JoshKG I did try to increase the width size but nothing happened. Could you think of something else that might be the reason why it happened>

Comment: how many rows is this? That's a pretty strange get request, could exceed character limits

Comment: @charlietfl The number of rows depends on the user, Though you have a point that this could exceed character limit.

Comment: @JoshKG I didn't notice it at first but then I found out that my div's display is set to none. Thank you!

Comment: @user3714598 glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JoshKG. I was able to fix the problem because of him.

To those who will have this kind of problem in the future. (Successfully getting the template/div that you want from server but not displaying.)

Use a tool to easily know what's going on (e.g. firebug, dev tools).

```
1) Go to the console tab and type this. (Replace "ThisIsMyDiv" with the Id that you need to find)
    document.getElementById("ThisIsMyDiv") 

2) You can easily determine if you've successfully gotten the div/template from server. If successful, right click on the parent element and choose "Reveal in Elements Panel" then check the CSS. Mine happens to have this
**display:none** which makes it clear why I could not see the page.
```

Please note that I'm using Chrome's dev tools in my example, firebug definitely has something similar to this, just play around with it.

Hope this would help a lost soul in the future.